# ¿Cuál de las formas es la correcta: "Dividir la torta entre Juan y yo" o "dividir la torta entre Juan y mí"?

Tags: traducción, pronombres, preposiciones

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de decir esa frase?

> I want to split the cake between me and Juan.

¿Sería entre **Juan y mí** o entre **Juan y yo** ?

Comment: Entre Juan y yo.  No sé por qué, la verdad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré esta [página](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/pronombres-y-determinantes/pronombres-personales) que explica sobre los pronombres en castellano:

> Excepciones:
>
> Con las preposiciones entre y según, no se pueden emplear los
> pronombres preposicionales mí y ti, sino los pronombres sujeto yo y
> tú.

Answer (score 0):

Entre Juan y yo. Siempre se pone a las otras personas delante y uno de último. Mí es un pronombre posesivo, en este caso se está diciendo que algo va a ser compartido por dos personas. Por lo tanto lo correcto es: Juan y yo.

Comment: Mi pregunta no es de la órden ya que en las dos formas viene **Juan** primero.

**mí** (con tilde) es el pronombre personal de primera persona singular [referencia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=P9vGzr7)

y **mi** (sin tilde) es el adjetivo posesivo de primera persona singular [referencia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=P9rNqLB|P9tBea9|P9vG3X8)

Comment: No hay problema en cambiar orden: *yo y Juan* está perfectamente bien dicho, si bien no es común.

Comment: Tu respuesta sería mejor si incluyeras el sustento de tus argumentos (están basados en la práctica, lo que te enseñó algo o en alguna literatura?)